# No assignment compatibility between Dictionary<int, List<T>> and IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<T>>?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I'm trying to pass a `Dictionary<int, List<T>>` into a constructor that requires an `IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<T>>`.

Unfortunately, the generic `IDictionary` is not defined as `IDictionary<TKey, out TValue>`. Perhaps this wouldn't make sense, but is there a cast that would allow me to pass my dictionary into the constructor?

The obvious cast (`(IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<T>>)dictionary`) fails at runtime.

Comment: can you show what the parameters are for the Constructor..? also show what the runtime error is as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, because that would not be safe:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> mydictionary = whatever;
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> converted = (Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>) mydictionary;
converted.Add(10, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } );
```

And you just added an array to a dictionary that can only hold lists. This isn't allowed because there is no way to make it safe.

You note that the dictionary interface is not covariant; it is precisely this reason why it cannot be covariant. The "out" in the covariant annotation is a mnemonic that is telling you "the value parameter is only used for output", but clearly the value parameter is used for input into a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I wrote the question rather hastily, and yes, I of course now realize that `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` contains members where `TValue` is an input (such as `Add()`), not just a returned value. Even a read-only dictionary type like `ILookup<TKey, TValue>`) wouldn't work because of the `Contains` method. The only solution seems to be to refactor the class I'm trying to instantiate so that it takes its own generic parameter `TEnumerable, where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<T>`...I just tried this and it works.

Comment: Another interesting question is why the new [`IReadOnlyDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136548.aspx) also isn't covariant (it's because of `KeyValuePair`).

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) method to get the required dictionary from the original one:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, List<int>> { { 1, new List<int> { 1 } } };
IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> id = 
                         d.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: It should be noted that this internally will call a constructor.  Anything you do will ultimately do this, since (as DanM pointed out) it's out `out TValue`.

Comment: @TimS. thank you and agree. This approach may suit, if only the target `IDictionary<>` will not be used to modify the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, but I needed to pass in the dictionary by reference, not make a copy.